# ASP.NetCore Website error when added to Service Fabric

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric

When I create a new Service Fabric solution containing ASP.Net Core website, I got this yellow exclamation mark that I don't know how to fix. Can anyone explain what is the error ?

[image: ScreenShot]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bug in the .net core tooling for VS 2015. It doesn't cause any problems other than showing that icon unnecessarily. You can safely ignore it.